# (Vanilla JS) Triggering click on a table cell using known index values

Tags: javascript, navigation, keyboard, click

I'm making a keyboard navigation for a table and I'm getting this error when I run the following code:

```
var newActiveCell = table.rows[activeRowIndex].cells[activeColumnIndex];
newActiveCell.click();
```

Error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'table.rows[activeRowIndex].cells')

It works with `.focus()` if I then do `activeCell = document.activeElement` but I was wondering if there's a better way to code that whole concept.

I haven't included the variable declarations and the function that handles keyboard input to save space in the post, but essentially what I'm trying to do is trigger a click on the cell for which I have the index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the undefined error for me, the row and column indexes I had defined before and whenever there was a keypress I incremented them as needed.

```
var newActiveCell = table.rows[activeRowIndex].cells[activeColumnIndex].focus();
activeCell = document.activeElement;

console.log(activeCell);
```